# typescript angular import module

Tags: angular, typescript, syntax

So i m following the angular tutorial [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1) and at the same time i m also reading about modules [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). Now inside the tutorial at some point, the author introduces this import:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

I could not find anywhere what the @ sign is in the above import. I mean what '@angular/core' suppose to do?

Comment: It's just the name of the package. The various Angular packages all have that prefix; see e.g. [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `'@angular/core'` with `@` means taking things from `npm`

with `angular/core` is nothing but the `folder/path`.

In angular '@angular/core' provides list of packages.
when you write

`import { Component } from '@angular/core';`

It gives you a way to make use of `component` which includes `template(html view), class(where logics implemented), and decorators(metadata from angular)`

when you write

`import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';`

then you will be able to use `Input properties` which is used to pass data from the `container component(parent)` to `nested component(child)`

when you write

`import { Component,Output } from '@angular/core';`

hen you will be able to use `Output properties` which is used to pass data from the `nested component` to `Container component`.

and this kind of many more things....(refer angular documentation) are there which is possible only when imported from `'@angular/core'`.

Comment: Thank you Sumit.This is clear now!

Comment: if it helps you out, Accept this answer.

Comment: I have accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The `@` is a npm feature that allows modules scoping. This means that the `core` module is part of the `angular` namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your note!